# How copy file from Windows to smartphone (Symbian) in dired mode?

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+.

When I connect (via microUSB) my smartphone (Nokia) to my computer, the Windows 10 success detect new device.
[image: Nokia]

And as result I can success copy/move file from Windows machine to smartphone.

Is it possible to do same in Emacs in dired mode?

Comment: I think that if you move focus to the address bar (the place where you see the "breadcrumbs" in the picture), Windows explorer will display the actual path to the current directory. You should then be able to use this path to perform regular file operations.

Comment: `C-x C-f' and input `This PC\Nokia C5-00.2\Memory card (MY PHONE)'. But it not help.  I get message `Create directory on D:/temp/This PC\Nokia C5-00.2\Memory card (MY PHONE) ?`

Comment: Nope, that's not the actual path. That's some rubbish Windows explorer displays on top of the actual path. It depends on the version of Windows and some other configuration settings, in which I'm not an expert, but there should be some way to get the actual path to the file the way filesystem sees it, not what is displayed in the explorer GUI. Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/679934/how-do-i-make-windows-explorer-display-the-file-path-instead-of-words-such-as-d

Comment: I think the actual problem is that the phone is not mapped to a drive letter but uses MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). Pityingly this stuff is handled very special by Windows. In Linux you just can mount mtp like other file systems. AFAIK that is not possible with Windows. You could try to set up your phone as mass storage device if the phone admits it.

Comment: @Tobias I think Symbian came way before MTP... there's a chance that Nokia provided a driver that exposes phone's storage as filesystem.

Comment: @wvxvw You wrote: "there's a chance that Nokia provided a driver that exposes phone's storage as filesystem". Okay that is then the next thing to be investigated. It is quite likely that one can set the usb connection to mass storage device in the system settings of the Nokia.